# Is WSL now available on LTSB?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As documented here and elsewhere, the windows subsystem for Linux is currently in beta and therefore not available on Windows 10 Long-term Service Branch. My experience on LTSB is that you could enable the WSL feature but the Windows Store wouldn't download the distro appx.

A few days ago I noticed an MS how-to beginning:

"There are several scenarios in which you may not be able (or want) to install WSL Linux distros via the Windows Store. Specifically, you may be running a

Windows Server or Long-Term Servicing (LTSB/LTSC) desktop OS SKU that doesn't support Windows Store, or your corporate network policies and/or admins do not permit Windows Store usage in your environment.

In these cases, while WSL itself is available, how do you download and install Linux distros in WSL if you can't access the store?"

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

This led me to think WSL would be available on LTSB. However, I find the same "unsupported version" error when I try to install the package. Also the MS how-to doc looks a little rushed (bad links, grammar/spelling errors) so I don't know how much stock to put in it.

Comment: WSL, is no longer a beta windows feature, hasn’t been for nearly a year

Comment: Depending on the version or the network policy, it is possible that Windows machines cannot get access to the Windows Store. For instance, [according to the MS website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual), some Windows LTSB can install the WSL feature but cannot access the Windows Store.

Comment: @Ramhound Well that it's not currently beta isn't particularly relevant. It was beta at the time of the last LTSB update.

Comment: @Jaime Isn't this the exact same thing I said (and same URL I posted)?

Comment: Probably, the problem trying to install a Linux distribution came with the version of WSL included in your Windows LTSB. The WSL included last year is not the same used today. If you need WSL today, you may try with old versions of the distributions or some installers for linux on WSL such as `WSL-Distrolauncher`, `WSLInstall` and `LxRunOffline`. A future version of the LTSB will include newer versions of the WSL and you will be able to run current distributions then. -- Do you know what is the effective version/build number of your Windows LTSB?

Comment: @Hasse1987 You seem to think it was still a beta feature but it isn’t

Comment: No, we can't install WSL on LTSB.

Comment: The last Windows 10 LTSB [is the 2016 release, equivalent to the 1607 version](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows-10/release-information). You cannot install the current version of WSL there. I think you must be able to install the initial/beta versions of the WSL, but I have not found an installer for that.

Comment: @Joy May I ask what you're basing that on?

Comment: @Jaime OK, thanks for the valuable idea. I had not considered looking for an older WSL version. I just can't understand why the MS document would say "In *these* cases, while WSL itself is available" unless it is available.

Comment: Checking old tutorials from [MS](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2016/06/07/step-by-step-enabling-bash-on-windows-10/) and [wsl-guide](http://wsl-guide.org/en/latest/installation.html#step-2-install-wsl), after you enable the WSL beta, you can run `bash` to download an Ubuntu distribution. That download does not work?

Comment: @Jaime Unfortunately, it doesn't, it throws the same "supported os version" error. Actually in the meantime I did figure out a way to get WSL to run on LTSB: rolling back some updates. Apparently it was "accidentally" included in an older version of LTSB: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1281

Comment: Note that MS updates the LTSB once every couple of years. The last one was in 2016.  Probably, the mentioned HowTo applies to a future LTSB version (hopefully, for this year) where the WSL will work as today in the developer channel.

Comment: According to the documentation, you can install WSL distributions from the Windows Store (by [using the installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) or by [extracting the files from the installer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server#extract-and-install-a-linux-distro)) only on Windows 10 Build 16215 / Windows Server Build 1709 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I can definitively answer this. Windows 10 LTSB 2016 is build 14393, and you need at least build 16215 to run WSL.  This may be coming in Windows 10 LTSC 2019 (they renamed LTSB to LTSC), but no guarantees.

Sources:

- [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 16241 for PC & Build 15230 for Mobile](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2017/07/13/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-16241-pc-build-15230-mobile/)
- [Ubuntu now available from the Windows Store!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/07/10/ubuntu-now-available-from-the-windows-store/)
- [Windows Server Installation Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-on-server)

Comment: I am not entirely sure your answer is correct.  `14393 and 16215 are in two entirely different releases.` one is the literal 1607 which of course is LTSB which does not include WSL.  `16215` is not even a stable build and is considered an Insider Preview build since it's before 16299.  None of your reference articles apply to LTSB/LTSC releases. `Windows 10 LTSC 2019` has not even been released yet.